# Twilio Flex Webchat - SecurityError: The operation is insecure - on for several phones

Tags: twilio, twilioflexwebchat

We have implemented Webchat using `twilio/flex-webchat-ui` and it works great on localhost and on production, also on mobile browsers

but - on a QA tests we are having, it seems like some mobile versions are not supported.

we get a `SecurityError: The operation is insecure.` message and `Actions: Error in action ToggleChatVisibility body: Expired token.`

this is the list of non-loading phones:

1. Iphone 11 Pro
2. Iphone 12 Pro
3. Iphone 12
4. Iphone 12mini
5. Iphone 13mini
6. Iphone 13 Pro max
7. Iphone 13

Does this ring any bells? is it true that Twillio will not support this?

```
      const webchatConfig: Record<any, any> = {
        MainHeader: {
          showImage: false,
          titleText: windowTitle
        },
        MessagingCanvas: {
          showTypingIndicator: true,
          memberDisplayOptions: {
            theirDefaultName: operatorName
          }
        }
      };

      const renderedWC = await renderWebChat({
        accountSid: accountSid,
        flexFlowSid: flowSid,
        logLevel: "INFO",
        chatFriendlyName: fullName,
        context: {
          friendlyName: fullName,
          priority: 1,
          campaignRunDebtId
        },

        colorTheme: {
          overrides: brandedColors
        },
        startEngagementOnInit: true,
        componentProps: webchatConfig,
        available: true
      });

      const { manager } = renderedWC;
      
      manager.strings.WelcomeMessage = welcomeMessage;
      manager.strings.PredefinedChatMessageAuthorName =
        operatorName;
      manager.strings.PredefinedChatMessageBody =
        predefinedFirstMessage;

      webChat.Actions.addListener("beforeSendMessage", (payload) => {
        payload.messageAttributes = {};
        payload.messageAttributes.fromWebChatDebtor = true;
        payload.messageAttributes.debtId = debtId;
      });

      webChat.Actions.addListener("afterToggleChatVisibility", () => {
        const webChatOpened =
          manager.store.getState().flex.session.isEntryPointExpanded;
        webChatOpened ? handleWebchatOpened() : handleWebchatClosed();
      });

      webChat.Actions.addListener("afterMinimizeChat", () => {
        handleWebchatClosed();
      });
      webChat.initWithStrings(manager.strings);
```